# Template pattern extension for subclasses with additional methods

Tags: java, templates, design-patterns

Best explained by an example:

```
interface Plane {
    public void flapsExtended();
    public void engineFullThrottle();
    public void takeOff();
    public void landed();
}


class Spitfire implements Plane {
}

class P51Mustang implements Plane {
}
```

So far my code was doing a good job. But as WW2 ended we had never jets with retractable landing gear.
So I added a new class for F22 which would need to add `retractLandingGear()` and `extendLandingGear` between the `takeOff` and `land` phase.

example:

```
class F22 {
        public void flapsExtended();
        public void engineFullThrottle();
        public void takeOff();
        public void retractLandingGear();
        public void extendLandingGear();
        public void landed();
}
```

Now how can I plugging F22's with those legacy code ( and legacy planes :) ) ?

Comment: Create a `interface ModernPlane extends Plane` and add other methods to it? Although you _still_ won't be able to access the new methods if you access your F-22 as a `Plane`...

Answer (score 0):

If you fully control all the code and are able to modify it, just modify the old classes so the new methods perform no-ops.

However, if you can't modify the old classes, you will have to make a new sub-interface with the extra methods and do instanceof checks to see which version of the interface the object you are working on uses and then cast accordingly.

This problem will be resolved in Java 8 when you can add default implementations to interfaces.